# AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute '_transfer_param_map_to_java'

Tags: python, pyspark, pipeline

I use pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator and Pipline to train a CrossValidatorModel named cv_model,after that,I want to persist the model, so i use cv_model.save to save my model,but an error occured：AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute '_transfer_param_map_to_java'
[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpdvR.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy1pm.png)

I do not know how to solve the error.
thanks for help me!

Comment: I also run into the same error. Do you happen to find an answer to that ?

Answer (score 8):

i  find a way to solve the problem myself:

```
pip_model = cv_model.bestModel
pip_model.write().overwrite().save("/Users/fushuai/PyCharmProject/CTREstimation/model")
```